# Presence push into Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams, user-presence

Since a couple of months it has been possible to read a users presence and Note via the Microsoft Graph API.

Does anyone know when Microsoft will open up for push and change of a users presence information in Teams via Graph, and will it be possible to do this by means of impersonating the user (that is on behalf of a user)?

We are currently doing the same for Skype for Business by means of the Skype Web API where we push mobile GSM call status information (busy, idle, detached) into SfB.

Comment: You may want to refer this with specific to MS Graph API & presence - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/presence?view=graph-rest-beta